# Strippin an element in xml and replacing the value of an element based on certain condition using xslt

Tags: xslt

I am getting stuck at a point where I need to remove an element from the input XML:

```
<message 
    xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<m_control>
    <control_timestamp>2013-06-06T14:55:37</control_timestamp>
    <initiator_id>ASL</initiator_id>
</m_control>
<m_content>
    <b_control>
        <quote_type>Single Company</quote_type>
        <quote_or_print>Quote And Print</quote_or_print>
        <generic_quote_ind>Yes</generic_quote_ind>
        <tpsdata>
            <tps_quote_type>Comparison</tps_quote_type>
        </tpsdata>
    </b_control>
    <application>
     <product>
        <tpsdata>
            <service_type>QuickQuote</service_type>
            <quote_type>Standard</quote_type>
        </tpsdata>
      </product>
    </application>
</m_content>
</message>
```

if `<tps_quote_type>` is `'Comparison'` then change the value of `<quote_type>` to `'Comparison'` and the `<tpsdata>` field should be removed. The output should look like below.

```
<message 
    xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<m_control>
     <control_timestamp>2013-06-06T14:55:37</control_timestamp>
     <initiator_id>ASL</initiator_id>
</m_control>
<m_content>
    <b_control>
         <quote_type>Comparison</quote_type>
         <quote_or_print>Quote And Print</quote_or_print>
         <generic_quote_ind>Yes</generic_quote_ind>
    </b_control>
   <application>
       <product>
          <tpsdata>
            <service_type>QuickQuote</service_type>
            <quote_type>Standard</quote_type>
          </tpsdata>
    </product>
    </application>
</m_content>
</message>
```

So far I have tried this XSLT, but I don't know how to remove `<tpsdata>` field from the output. Could anyone help me in this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" 
    extension-element-prefixes="dp"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- identity with closing tags -->
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="quoteType">
       <xsl:value-of select="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and  local- name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name() ='m_content']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='b_control']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='quote_type']"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="tpsQuoteType">
        <xsl:value-of select="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='m_content']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='b_control']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='tpsdata']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='tps_quote_type']"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='m_content']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='b_control']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='quote_type']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$tpsQuoteType = 'Comparison' ">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:text>Comparison</xsl:text>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|namespace::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you noticed that your handling of those elements with a namespace is a little painful. Just add the `http://www.origoservices.com` namespace to your XSLT and the pain goes away.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:o="http://www.origoservices.com" 
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" 
    extension-element-prefixes="dp"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn date"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="o:b_control/o:quote_type[../o:tpsdata/o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:text>Comparison</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="o:tpsdata[o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes

- Most of your "plumbing" is not necessary.
- Template match expressions don't need to be a full path.
- Use match expressions rather than `<xsl:choose>` to pinpoint elements you want to change.
- Start with a basic identity template, overriding it as needed with more specific templates. This makes your live much easier than starting with a modified identity template.
- Use empty templates to remove specific elements.

Comment: It is working as expcted. As I am new in XSLT, could you please explain how the below statement works?

<xsl:template match="o:b_control/o:quote_type[../o:tpsdata/o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']">

Comment: It matches any `o:quote_type` element that belongs to `o:tps_quote_type` of `'Comparison'`, just as you defined in the question. What part of the the expression do you have difficulties with? I'll try to explain.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I understood that, it will test if <tps_quote_type> is 'Quotation', then it will match the template <quote_type>... Could you please explain why have you used '../' syntax in the test box? Is there any article on web which can explain this syntax in more detail? Just wanted to learn more about it.

Comment: The `..` moves one node up, just like in directory paths. After `o:b_control/o:quote_type` the selection context is on the `<quote_type>` element. From there you need to navigate to the parent element (`..`) and from *there* you can easily select `tpsdata/tps_quote_type`. The alternative would be `o:b_control/o:quote_type[following-sibling::o:tpsdata/o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']`, but navigation through the parent with `..` is both shorter and more robust.

Comment: Thank You Tomalak, this answers all my questions. I will post here, if I have nay further questions. Thanks again!!

Comment: If you have anything directly related to this particular question, you could post another comment here. If you have an unrelated question, it's better to set up a new post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp regexp fn dpconfig" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" >

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>    

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='tpsdata']/*[local-name()='quote_type']">
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> Found quote_type </xsl:message> 
        <xsl:variable name = "First"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='message']/*[local-name()='m_content']/*[local-name()='b_control']/*[local-name()='tpsdata']/*[local-name()='tps_quote_type']/text()"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name = "Second">
                <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> Second:<xsl:value-of select = "$Second"/></xsl:message> 
        <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> First: <xsl:value-of select = "$First"/> </xsl:message>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Second = $First">
            <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> Stand and Comp are same </xsl:message>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>


        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> Stand and Comp are different </xsl:message>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace(*[local-name()='quote_type'],'','',$First)"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>


</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='b_control']/*[local-name()='tpsdata']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer? What does this code do? How does it solve the question?

Comment: HI Alexander,
 Previous code was only used to remove "tps_quote_type".
So i have replaced with the new code , so it will do what expected.

Comment: let me know , if you are unable to make it out.